# How to Stub a jquery selector in Sinon js

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, sinon

I'm doing some unit testing, and I stuck trying to stub this method.
I'm also using materialize for dropdown, which I believe is related.
Does someone faced this problem and can help?

My code goes

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    $('.dropdown-trigger-filter').dropdown({belowOrigin: true, alignment: 'right', closeOnClick: false});
    this.controller.isFirstLoginRedirect(this.props);
}
```

My test:

```
describe('Home Component', async () => {
    let container = props => { return <Home store={store} {...props} />;    };

    it('should render correctly', () => {
        const props = {};
        const wrapper = mount(shallow(container(props)).get(0));
        const tree = renderer.create(container(props)).toJSON();

        expect(tree).matchSnapshot();
    });

    it('should change state of selected tab to quotes ', () => {
        const props = {};
        const wrapper = mount(shallow(container(props)).get(0));
        const $ = sinon.stub();
        $.withArgs('.dropdown-trigger-filter').returns({});
        (wrapper.find('.tab').at(0)).simulate('click');
        expect(wrapper.state('selectedTab')).equal('##quotes');
        expect(wrapper.debug()).matchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

Error:

```
 TypeError: $(...).dropdown is not a function
```

Comment: It's not a function.  You are returning a stubbed `{}` with nothing in it.  Now if you returned `{dropdown:function(){}}` then it would exist, :)

Comment: That actually works!, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate error is that you have stubbed `$`, and now there is no more `dropdown` property on it. If you wanted this to work, you would need to return a mocked `dropdown` function as well as any other jquery function you happen to call.

In the end your tests will just be reflections of all the jquery calls you make. They will be complex and brittle since you need to create so many stubs just to regenerate the environment you are working in.

So, for this reason, you should not be trying to stub jquery at all. If you find that you have to do this, then it's likely you need to refactor in order to make your tests simpler.

In this case, you want to be testing that the dom you are using works with the jquery calls.  So, you will want to generate some DOM and run some expectations against it, something like this:

```
it('should change state of selected tab to quotes ', () => {
    const props = {};
    const wrapper = generateCompleteDom();
    (wrapper.find('.tab').at(0)).simulate('click');
    expect(wrapper.state('selectedTab')).equal('##quotes');
    expect(wrapper.debug()).matchSnapshot();
```

Notice that it looks almost identical to what you have already, except that you are not stubbing anything and you are just generating a more complete DOM (whatever is necessary for your test).